# Action columns not displaying Edit options

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6, sort, action, custom-admin-grid

[image]

`<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action"> <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item> <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item> </item> </argument> </actionsColumn>`

Comment: hello Midhun M if you have any issue magento 2 related then you are talk with discord. so my discord id is = mohit_gento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello dear please go to /var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_uiform_blog_listing.xml

here is my module name Test_Uiform add below your file

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Test\Uiform\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\BlogActions">
        <settings>
            <indexField>blog_id</indexField>
            <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
            <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
```

here blog_id my table primary so you can change your requirement.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/BlogActions.php

created this add below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
  declare(strict_types=1);

  namespace Test\Uiform\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

  class BlogActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
  {

const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'test_uiform/blog/edit';

const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'test_uiform/blog/delete';

protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param array $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['blog_id'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'edit' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                            [
                                'blog_id' => $item['blog_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                            [
                                'blog_id' => $item['blog_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete '.$item['name']),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a '.$item['name'].' record?')
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $dataSource;
}
}
```

above file blog_id change your id.

above file you can see below two const so please understand the details.

```
 const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'test_uiform/blog/edit';

const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'test_uiform/blog/delete';
```

here 'test_uiform' is router-id so we are set in routes.xml

so please check and compare the routes.xml file in the below directory.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route frontName="test_uiform" id="test_uiform">
        <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Test_Uiform"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

So above file change the name of your module.

test_uiform/blog/edit => **blog** is my controller name and **edit** is action so you can change as per your requirement. below I will add both files.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog/Edit.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Uiform\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog;

class Edit extends \Test\Uiform\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog
   {

protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
}

/**
 * Edit action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    // 1. Get ID and create model
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('blog_id');
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Web30india\Uiform\Model\Blog::class);
    
    // 2. Initial checking
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        if (!$model->getBlogId()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Blog no longer exists.'));
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('test_uiform_blog', $model);
    
    // 3. Build edit form
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->initPage($resultPage)->addBreadcrumb(
        $id ? __('Edit Blog') : __('New Blog'),
        $id ? __('Edit Blog') : __('New Blog')
    );
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Blogs'));
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getBlogId() ? __('Edit Blog %1', $model->getBlogId()) : __('New Blog'));
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

/var/www/html/projeect/app/code/Test/Uiform/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog/Delete.php

```
<?php
   /**
    * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
   declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Uiform\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog;

class Delete extends \Test\Uiform\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog
{

 /**
 * Delete action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    // check if we know what should be deleted
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('blog_id');
    if ($id) {
        try {
            // init model and delete
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Web30india\Uiform\Model\Blog::class);
            $model->load($id);
            $model->delete();
            // display success message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You deleted the Blog.'));
            // go to grid
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // display error message
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            // go back to edit form
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['blog_id' => $id]);
        }
    }
    // display error message
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t find a Blog to delete.'));
    // go to grid
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
}
```

above both files blog_id to change your id.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Uiform\Controller\Adminhtml;

abstract class Blog extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $_coreRegistry;
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Test_Uiform::top_level';

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Init page
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function initPage($resultPage)
{
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu(self::ADMIN_RESOURCE)
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Test'), __('Test'))
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Blog'), __('Blog'));
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

please check below screenshot.[image]

i hope that is work for you. if any issue then tell me. please accept my answer and upvote me.